# Monitor a Process using NETSTAT

Tags: windows, networking

Question => Is there a way to see the number of bytes sent and received or the transfer rate of a particular process using NETSTAT in windows ?

Explaination - 
netstat -ab => shows the process with its name and IP and Port. 
netstat -sp IP => shows the total number bytes transferred by all the processes.

I want to see the Bytes transferred of a Particular process.

UPDATE - Is there any other command except NETSTAT, through which I can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid not. the `-s` switch shows protocol statistics, not stats per port. The available protocols for `-sp` are `tcp, udp, icmp, ip, tcpv6, udpv6, icmpv6, or ipv6`, so you can't dig down to port/process. See the details for `-s` and `-p` here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff961504.aspx

Internally [Windows uses the IPHLPAPI.dll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat#Platform_specific_remarks), calling the [appropriate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366071%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for each protocol specified. In the case of TCP it calls [GetTCPStatistics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366020%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which returns the [MIB_TCPSTATS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure. This structure is not capable of storing per port statistics. I believe that the values you are seeing are coming from the `dwInSegs` and `dwOutSegs` members.